# How to write a Tempfile as binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When trying to write a string / unzipped file to a [Tempfile](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) by doing:

```
temp_file = Tempfile.new([name, extension])
temp_file.write(unzipped_io.read)
```

Which throws the following error when I do this with an image:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError - "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

When researching it I found out that this is caused because Ruby tries to write files with an encoding by default (UTF-8). But the file should be written as binary, so it ignores any file specific behavior.

Writing regular [`File`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html) you would be able to do this as following:

```
File.open('/tmp/test.jpg', 'rb') do |file| 
  file.write(unzipped_io.read)
end
```

How to do this in `Tempfile`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Tempfile.new` passes options to [`File.open`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/File.html#method-c-open) which accepts the [options from `IO.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-Options), in particular:

> **:binmode**
>   If the value is truth value, same as “b” in argument `mode`.

So to open a tempfile in binary mode, you'd use:

```
temp_file = Tempfile.new([name, extension], binmode: true)

temp_file.binmode?          #=> true
temp_file.external_encoding #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

In addition, you might want to use [`Tempfile.create`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-c-create) which takes a block and automatically closes and removes the file afterwards:

```
Tempfile.create([name, extension], binmode: true) do |temp_file|
  temp_file.write(unzipped_io.read)
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is `IO.binwrite(path, file_content)`

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the solution in an old Ruby forum post, so I thought I would share it here, making it easier for people to find:

https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/ruby-binary-temp-file/116791

Apparently `Tempfile` has an undocumented method `binmode`, which changes the writing mode to binary and thus ignoring any encoding issues:

```
temp_file = Tempfile.new([name, extension])
temp_file.binmode
temp_file.write(unzipped_io.read)
```

Thanks *unknown* person who mentioned it on ruby-forums.com in 2007!

Comment: From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html): _"[...] you can in fact call any File instance method on a Tempfile object"_

Comment: From the docs for [File](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html) in the Methods list, there is no result searching for `binmode`.

Comment: I see my issue now. I looked only 1 depth, expecting to find my method in [File](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html), but I should have looked into the next depth where File inherits [IO](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html)